# Extending block context menu

Tags: episerver

I wonder if it somehow is possible to extend the block context menu in episerver? What we want to do is to somehow get two display option menus and to use them combined to render our output.

[Screenshot of the block context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul2wL.png)

We would like to give the user the possibility to have two display options like this:

1. RIGHT | LEFT | CENTER
2. Render for 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 columns

This could be solved with only some CSS magic, but we do not want the behaviour overall. Only if defined.

Hope to get some input on this :)

Comment: The context menus are composed by a command provider model that you can hook into, but I'm not sure there's an "easy fix" to achieve what you're describing. :/

Comment: You'll get a bit on the way by using this https://github.com/valdisiljuconoks/EPiBootstrapArea, also check the source, all you need is there

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ted Nyberg, I don't think there is an easy fix to this either. To achieve this behavior, I think you will have to modify how Display Options are retrieved.

[Mattias Olsson wrote a blog post on localizing Display Options in 2015.](https://getadigital.com/no/blogg/filtered-display-option-menu-based-on-content-type-in-episerver/) It does not solve your problem, but modifies the way display options are fetched from Episerver. I would suggest implementing that, and adding an extra rest store (or modifying the existing) for your secondary display option type, and finally modifying the dojo widget to accommodate the new display options.